# MySQL JSON_ARRAY_APPEND Remove unnecessary \ and "

Tags: mysql, json, backslash

I have in mysql this JSON format that is fine:

```
{"2017": {"1": {"payed": 0, "charge": 0}}}
```

Now i need to add another year and that JSON now looks like this:

```
{"2017": {"1": {"payed": 0, "charge": 0}}, "2018": {"1": {"payed": 0, "charge": 0}}}
```

I try it using this MySQL Code:

```
UPDATE calculation 
SET payment = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(payment, '$', '{"2018": {"1": {"payed": 0,"charge": 0}}}');
```

And i was getting this:

```
[{"2017": {"1": {"payed": 0, "charge": 0}}}, "{\"2018\": {\"1\": {\"payed\": 0,\"charge\": 0}}}"]
```

So you see that I'm having backslashes \ and need to remove it and also unnecessary at beginning and ending " so how to remove it to get desired this to look exactly like this:

```
{"2017": {"1": {"payed": 0, "charge": 0}}, "2018": {"1": {"payed": 0, "charge": 0}}}
```

Comment: Kindly mark the answer as accepted if it served the purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to **CAST** the string as JSON.

Try this out:

```
UPDATE calculation 
SET payment = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(payment, '$', CAST('{"2018": {"1": {"payed": 0,"charge": 0}}}' as JSON));
```

Comment: In mariadb, you have to use `JSON_COMPACT(x)` instead of `CAST(x as JSON)` https://github.com/MariaDB/server/commit/6f6d0531dca711f13842cfca761afd073c595f57